# JavaScript child object access own values

Tags: javascript, oop, object, parent-child

So I have this one big parent object which has multiple childs that need to calculate their values using the parents values and their own values. Here's a quick example to show you the idea:

```
function Parent(stuff, otherStuff){
    this.pValue = 4;
    this.child1 ={
        childStuff: this.pValue*stuff.stuffValue,
        childStuff2: childstuff*otherStuff.otherValue
    }
}
```

This thing is called in another part of the code with appropriate variables:

```
var thething = new Parent(stuff, otherStuff);
```

I need access to the childvariables of thething and everything needs to be recalculated when variables in stuff or otherStuff changes.

So how can I access the 'childstuff' value when calculating childStuff2? Unfortunately I have to juggle all these values from different places and some of them are dependant on eachother so the whole thing is a little bit messy, hence trying to do things this way.

Still learning so any and all input is welcome and appreciated. Not a native english speaker so sorry for any errors. Thanks.

Comment: The code you posted will generate syntax errors. What exactly is it that you want to do?

Comment: `childstuff` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), it's basically a way of performing GOTOs. It isn't a variable or a property, and you can't have a label in the middle of a statement, so `childStuff2:` throws an error.

Comment: If you want a simple object, then get rid of your functions and rewrite your code to use objects. If you want to implement a class-like system using functions and prototypes, then start and again and separate your business logic from your data structures (i.e. design your classes and then create instances of them with your data in them).

Comment: childStuff was in parentheses to highlight it. Wasn't the best idea, edited the code.

The parent is called in another place var thing = new parent(stuff, otherStuff)

There are also about 15 child objects in the parent that I need to access in another part of the app, where the parent is initiated. Also the specs I have is a messed up excel so it could be that I'm totally in the woods right now with everything.

Comment: @muhonne — apostrophes are not parentheses and the code threw an error before it reached them (and it still does throw that error).

Comment: @Quentin the example is just to show you the idea, it won't work anyway without the proper attributes so I didn't bother checking syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for:

```
function Child(pValue){
  this.childStuff = pValue * stuff.stuffValue;
  this.childStuff2 = this.childstuff * otherStuff.otherValue;
}

function Parent(stuff, otherStuff){
  this.pValue = 4;
  this.children = [];
}

Parent.prototype.addChild = function(){
  var newChild = new Child(this.pValue);
  this.children.push(newChild);
}
```

To create a parent with three children:

```
var aParent = new Parent('foo', 'bar');

aParent.addChild();
aParent.addChild();
aParent.addChild();
```

Keep in mind that if `aParent.pValue` changes, the properties for the children will not be recalculated. But maybe that is what you want.

Comment: There are around 30 pValues and every child calculates their values differently so this would make the code too complicated. But I think it would work if the circumstances were different.

Answer (score -1):

What I needed was a 'quick fix' for a child to access it's own values. Since this seems to not be possible I just set the value outside the child:

```
function Parent(stuff, otherStuff){
    this.pValue = 4;
    this.child1 ={
        childStuff: this.pValue*stuff.stuffValue,
        //childStuff2: childstuff*otherStuff.otherValue
    };
    this.child1.childstuff2 = this.child1.childstuff*otherstuff.otherValue;
}
```